# sql server "bridging" data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have the following mssql table:

```
+-------------------------+---+---+---+---+---+
|          date           | A | B | C | D | E |
+-------------------------+---+---+---+---+---+
| 2017-02-02 00:00:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:01:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:02:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:03:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:04:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:05:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:06:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:07:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:08:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:09:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
+-------------------------+---+---+---+---+---+
```

I need to write a query that changes the 0s to 1s on column D if the state of D goes to zero for less than 5 minutes. In other words I need to "bridge" the two consecutive 1s at the extremities of the 0s if the state 0 is smaller than ten mins.

Is it possible to perform this operation using T-SQL (SQL SERVER 2014)?
Thank you.

Example1:

```
+-------------------------+---+---+---+---+---+
|          date           | A | B | C | D | E |
+-------------------------+---+---+---+---+---+
| 2017-02-02 00:00:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:01:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:02:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:03:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:04:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:05:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:06:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:07:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:08:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:09:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
+-------------------------+---+---+---+---+---+
```

The query should return

```
+-------------------------+---+---+---+---+---+
|          date           | A | B | C | D | E |
+-------------------------+---+---+---+---+---+
| 2017-02-02 00:00:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:01:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:02:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:03:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:04:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:05:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:06:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:07:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:08:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:09:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
+-------------------------+---+---+---+---+---+
```

example 2:

```
+-------------------------+---+---+---+---+---+
|          date           | A | B | C | D | E |
+-------------------------+---+---+---+---+---+
| 2017-02-02 00:00:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:01:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:02:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:03:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:04:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:05:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:06:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:07:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:08:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:09:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
+-------------------------+---+---+---+---+---+
```

the query should return

```
+-------------------------+---+---+---+---+---+
|          date           | A | B | C | D | E |
+-------------------------+---+---+---+---+---+
| 2017-02-02 00:00:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:01:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:02:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:03:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:04:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:05:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:06:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:07:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:08:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2017-02-02 00:09:00.000 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
+-------------------------+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Please show your desired results - I'm not understanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: Exactly, that question made no sense.  Okay, so if a column D value gets set to 0 - woah !  That's less than 10 minutes - so we need to immediately set it to 1.  And then it's not 0 anymore.  Voila, job done.

Comment: It makes sense if you try to make sense of it, but I suppose that doesn't afford the same opportunity to feel superior.  If a series of 0's isn't at least 10 minutes long, OP wants to replace the 0's in that series with 1's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE** - You probably got the idea from the original, but I used the wrong aggregate function some of the time; I think I have it untangled now.

So... If a row's value is 0, but the time between the most recent preceding row with a 1 and the earliest subsequent row with a 1 is less than 10 minutes, you want to change that row's value to a 1.  And in all other cases you leave the value as is.  Right?

The time of the most recent row with a 1 can be expressed as `max(case when D = 1 then date end) over (order by date rows unbounded preceding)`.

Likewise the time of the earliest subsequent row with a 1 can be expressed as `min(case when D = 1 then date end) over (order by date rows unbounded following)`.

Find the interval between them; if the dates are all aligned to an even minute, then you can simply use `datediff`:

```
datediff(minute, max(case when D=1 then date end) over (order by date rows unbounded preceding),
                 min(case when D=1 then date end) over (order by date rows unbounded following))
```

Then apply case logic.

```
case when -- the above expression
          < 10 then 1 else D end
```